# Checking if file exists in Kotlin without creating the file

Tags: android, kotlin, sharedpreferences, file-exists

Relevant answers checked but they don't exactly address my situation.

At the beginning of my application it is checked if a file exists by the code: `someFile.exists()`. However I found out that if the user navigates inside the app using menu items and back button the code behaves like `someFile` is created -although the app fragment to create and write into `someFile` is not triggered at all. I suppose this is because a File object is created by the system to run the `exists()` method, and this object causes `someFile.exists()` to return `true` in the next call.

1. How can I solve this?
2. Is there a bulletproof method to check if a sharedPreferences file exists or not?

Comment: The File class will not create a file if you only check if a file exists.

Comment: As long as you do not tell from which class 'someFile' is an instance you let us guess.

Comment: A shared preferences file? Some file? Where are you talking about? Code please.

Comment: blackapps, Thanks for the reply. I couldn't share the code because I modified it a lot. When I debugged the previous code I saw that in the line `if (someFile.exists())` the code returned `true` although I am sure that I manually didn't put any string inside of `someFile`. Anyway I will try to recover the previous code so that you can understand better.

Comment: @blackapps I tried code again using Log.v. It looks like once `onCreate` started it runs till the end even if a new activity is started in the middle (for example by an if statement). If this is the case, it might explain the reason the file is created.